# How to correctly get JSON value?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json array

```
var currencyformats =
{"USD":[
    {'symbol':'$', 'left':true}
],
    "UAH":[
        {'symbol':'₴', 'left':true}
    ],
    "EUR":[
        {'symbol':'€', 'left':false}
    ]
};
```

How retreive '₴' ?
I tried this (in cookie "to" I've "UAH")

```
currencyformats[$.cookie("to")].symbol
```

but I've obtained `undefined`

Comment: Try `currencyformats[$.cookie("to")][0].symbol`

Comment: Pedantic notes: that's not an array, and it's also not really JSON. JSON insists on double-quotes for string constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that under each country code, you've defined an array with a single object. That means that after you access the country code, you'll need to also access the first index in the array.

So, assuming the cookie is set to the value that you're expecting:

```
currencyformats[$.cookie("to")][0].symbol;
```